# Honeycomb ActionBar Items - Crashing App

Tags: android, menu, crash, menuitem, android-actionbar

I am developing an Android app for devices 2.1 Eclair -> 3.0 Honeycomb. I am now moving onto creating a user settings area. I have hit a snag with Menu & ActionBar Items.

I created a menu xml resource with my items and icons in it, then I hooked it up in java with this:

I added these imports on top of what I already had:

```
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
```

And then this code in my activity as the [Android Developers site said to](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html):

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.pixelappmenu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menuItem_Help:
        helpDialogGo();
        return true;
    case R.id.menuItem_Settings:
        settingsActivityGo();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

(This is all I have added since it was working fine. I even commented all this new stuff out and it started working again on Honeycomb.)

This worked when I tested it on Froyo - the menu appeared with the titles and icons as its supposed to, but when I try to launch the app on my Honeycomb tablet, it force closes without even showing the app for a split second.

Some other possibly relevant code:

extract from androidmanifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk 
    android:minSdkVersion="7" 
    android:targetSdkVersion="11" />
```

pixelappmenu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:title="Help"
        android:id="@+id/menuItem_Help"/>
    <item
        android:title="Settings"
    android:id="@+id/menuItem_Settings"
    android:onClick="onMenuItemClick_Settings"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: Do you have any message in logcat ?

Comment: @rabs83: Try getting rid of the `android:onClick` attribute -- you're not using it, and I don't see it employed very often, so that might be the source of your difficulty. Beyond that, as @Gregory suggested, use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to examine LogCat and look at the stack trace associated with your "force close".

Comment: @CommonsWare, I have done that, it is not causing the issue. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @rabs83: Then use adb logcat, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to examine LogCat and look at the stack trace associated with your "force close".

Comment: I have fixed my issue, I just have to wait til tomorrow to answer my own question because my rep < 100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix.

In the menu xml file (res/menu/mymenu.xml - or whatever you called your file), you need to declare that the menu item is allowed to be on the ActionBar. You do this by placing

```
android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
```

Within your item in your XML.

Sample code is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:title="Help"
    android:id="@+id/menuItem_Help"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"/>
<item
    android:title="Settings"
    android:id="@+id/menuItem_Settings"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: Also, if you want to just display the text, set it to "ifRoom" and if you want it to display in the overflow menu, you can set it to "never".